# Why do Grignard reagents form?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Why does magnesium insert itself between a carbon atom and halogen atom? Can anyone give any vague idea about why this occurs?

Also does a Grignard reagent only form when there is carbon atom and halogen atom with single bond between them? For example, can magnesium insert between the carbon and oxygen atoms of a carbonyl?

Comment: Reactions happen because of decrease in chemical potential associated with it. More precisely they happen if activation energy is provided, products are stable thermodynamically or kinetically and there's a viable pathway for it. Are youu asking about pathway or what?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a very interesting question that till today, not everyone agrees the precise mechanism as to how it works. Here is one with homolytic fission:

[image]

For your second query, I don't think it is feasible as the $\ce{C=O}$ carbonyl bond is rather stable.

Comment: The answer presents a mechanistic hypothesis, but the question is asking why the reaction happens. The answer needs to include some rationale why the mechanism makes sense.